# how to call a function if disable field change

Tags: angularjs

Here my requirement is that i am using three fields. When 1st and 2nd fields are modified then effect a third field and the third field then disables.When third field change, then immediately i want to call a function without ng-watch.Is it possible..?

Comment: Could you include some code to show what you're trying to do? To react to changes to fields, you could simply use `ng-change`, which takes a callback expression.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use  **`$scope.$watch`**

```
 $scope.$watch('myVar', function() {
     alert('hey, you have changed!');
 });
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively, You can try using **`$on()`**, **`$emit()`** and **`$broadcast()`**.

Comment: thanks for quick reply.but I mention without watch function

Comment: I am not understanding $on() function,how can I call from html to controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149775/discussion-between-maxi-and-sajeetharan).